# Bad Opengl output, SDL2 x86

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl

I have been working on a small hobby project for over a year now. Its written in C++, using SDL/Image/Mixer and Minizip. It uses OpenGL for rendering.

Till July of this year I had been maintaining and testing both x64 and x86 versions of the code. Both compiled without any changes to the original code and ran exactly the same.

However, around August i moved the code upto SDL 2.0 from 1.2.15 and started only maintaining and testing the x64 version. Now when i try to build a x86 version I am getting the below problem.

```
Correct Output
```

[image]

```
Incorrect Output
```

[image]

-
Things I have tried:

- gDebugger: both version of the code create the same type of context.
  However accumulate buffer is 64 bits in both. Cannot find a way to
  disable it.
- ran it through drmemory: no alarming memory or heap    corruption
- check contexts on creation: both version create the same    value
  context in SDL, both generate the same "No OpenGL context has    been
  made current" even after calling SDL_GL_MakeCurrent, but the x64
  version works, the x86 debug version gives a black screen, and the
  x86 release version gives the above output.

Both the x64 and x86 version are the same exact code, which used to compile and work properly before SDL 2.0. I am not sure if its a bug in SDL, or something i did wrong. Let me if you need more information on this.

Update:

- I am using pure GL 1.1 code only, so no shaders or vbo's. Using only glVertexPointer, and associated glColorPointer and glTexCoordPointer functions. all arrays are defined as GL_types, with the gl functions given the pointer to the client memory. All textures are rendered as quads.

  ```
  GLfloat vertex_array_3f[12];
  //Initialize array
  glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertex_array_3f);
  //set color and tex pointers
  glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);
  ```
- The context type I am requesting is 2.1, but instead i get a backward compatible context. Doesnt cause any issues in the x64 version.
- I also changed over the from VS2010 express to VS2012 express during the same period. But i do remember it compiling succesfully for x86 for VS2012 express.

edit: Has any one experience anything like this before? I am doing some testing in the meanwhile, if i find anything will post the findings below.

Comment: More information would definitely be helpful, in particular whether you are using VBOs or client memory, how you setup your vertex pointers and any relevant vertex shader. The big thing that changes between an x86 and x86-64 build is the size of pointer types, incorrectly written vertex array pointers may be producing what I can only imagine right now are incorrect texture coordinate issues.

Comment: updated the question with more information. let me know if you need more.

Comment: Regarding "backward compatible" contexts. The distinction between core and forward/backward compatible was only introduced with OpenGL 3.x and only truly settled with language introduced in OpenGL 3.2. If you ask for a 2.1 (or older) context on a driver that implements 3.2 or greater it will probably report the version string as something like "X.Y backward compatible", where X.Y is greater than the version you requested; this is normal.

Comment: yeah, i was aware of the way backward compatible context part. what about the accumulation buffer? it says 64 bits even for the x86 application.

Comment: The accumulation buffer actually has nothing to do with the CPU word size, it is part of the framebuffer that literally accumulates color. Much like you may have a 16/24/32-bit depth buffer, you can even have 128-bit accumulation buffers (though not common in modern desktop hardware -- SGI had some truly exotic hardware back in the day, http://www.spec.org/gwpg/pastissues/Oct98/opc/SGI/summary/drv/SGI.008.html). In fact, if I recall there are a couple of GDI-only formats in Windows that offer 128-bit accumulation.

Comment: Can this be a case of bad context creation by SDL2. Because i was using the same functions and operation on SDL 1.2.15 and never faced this issue. is it also possible that this is a bad driver issue, where it fails to correctly interpret x86 commands in a x64 enviroment? Or is it Win7x64 and visual studio 2012 express problems? any ideas?